# Error while sending ( character with sendkeys in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am getting the following error when I try to send to send a "(" or ")" character using SendKeys .In my vbscript.

```
Invalid procedure call or argument
```

My script:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 100
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\readme.txt", 1)
Wshshell.SendKeys "!@#$%^&*()"
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strCharacters = objFile.Read(1)

    WshShell.SendKeys strCharacters
Loop
```

It does not send the "(" and ")" when I try to send them before the loop but shows no error and continues till a little further where it encounters another "(" character and stops with the error.

Comment: The code in your post executes without any problems at all.  It's syntactically correct.  Although the script doesn't actually perform any useful function.  It reads a text file and types its contents into nothingness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parenthesis are considered a special character and need to be surrounded in braces. See this [link](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/wsh/quickref/wshshell_SendKeys.html) for more details.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 100
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\readme.txt", 1)
Wshshell.SendKeys "!@#$%^&*{(}{)}"
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strCharacters = objFile.Read(1)

    WshShell.SendKeys strCharacters
Loop
```

Comment: Parenthesis are NOT special characters--per your link.

Comment: Any other symbols I need to look out for!

Comment: Take a look at this list: [Special Sendkeys characters](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/wsh/quickref/wshshell_SendKeys.html)

Comment: @GuidoGautier Parenthesis are **NOT** on that list.  They are not restricted characters.  Furthermore, the code in the OP's post executes without any error at all, despite the fact that it doesn't actually *do* anything.

Comment: @Nilpo, you are completely right. Was linking it for the fact that is does contain the special characters for this function.

Comment: @Nilpo they are special characters. *"The SendKeys method uses some characters as modifiers of characters (instead of using their face-values). This set of special characters consists of **parentheses**, brackets, braces, and the: plus sign `+`, caret `^`, percent sign `%` and tilde `~`"*. - [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/8c6yea83%28v%3dvs.80%29).