# Code 800A0005 when using set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile

Tags: vbscript

I have searched this error code numerous times and have gone to numerous sites to read responses.  Long story short, still haven't found a solution.

One page referenced: [Error while sending ( character with sendkeys in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090602/error-while-sending-character-with-sendkeys-in-vbscript)

Here is my code:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return = WshShell.Run("C:\Downloads\software\putty.exe -load navstat")

DIM date 
date = 301113

DIM tran1
tran1 = TAFFY

set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\Entries1.txt", ForReading) 

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream 
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine 
    If InStr(strLine, "JFK.GREKI3.MARTN..TOPPS") Then 
        set indi = 2 
        set tran1 = TOPPS 
    End If
Loop
```

What's going on:  I am scanning a .txt file (Entries1.txt) for text strings.  If they occur I need to set corresponding indi values (so when indi is used later as a variable it will use the correct #) and change the tran1 variables as well.

For some reason I'm getting an error at:

```
set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile
```

The error is

> Invalid procedure call or argument
>   Code: 800A0005

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're getting the error at the line you indicate, all of the code beyond that is irrelevant clutter and can be removed from your question; it's meaningless, because execution never gets to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `ForReading` portion of the line allows it to execute on my system using the following code:

```
'Saved in D:\TempFiles\TypeFile.vbs
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\Test.txt") 

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream 
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine 
    wscript.echo strLine
Loop
```

I tested using a simple `Test.txt` containing the following:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
```

I tested it using the following at a command prompt:

```
D:\TempFiles>cscript TypeFile.vbs
```

I received this output:

[image]

Note: An additional problem you'll encounter is using `set` on this line (and perhaps the one that follows it):

```
set indi = 2
```

`indi` is a simple variable, not an object, and therefore there's no need for `set`. Just assign the value directly:

```
indi = 2
```

Comment: What happens if you copy that exact path and filename to the clipboard, **exactly as it is in your code**, open Notepad, use **File->Open** from the menu, and paste it into the filename entry and click "Open"?

Comment: The document I want to scan opens like I would expect.

Comment: Thanks.  I modified it and now it gets to set indi = 2 before it errors.  Hmmmm, Error: Object required: '[number:2]'
I haven't researched this error code yet, so I'll go do that now.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the question you asked here. I've answered that one. :-) We can't be expected to debug every single line of your script. (I'll bail you out on this one, but in the future ask a separate question.) Remove the `set`, leaving `indy = 2`. It's a simple variable, and doesn't need to be `set`.

Comment: You're very correct.  I've marked your answer as accepted.  I appreciate your time and input.

Comment: Now I have.  Thanks a lot.  You saved me a lot of time both tonight and at work.  I just ran it and it runs, albeit inputs incorrect info, but I can take care of that.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

While [Ken's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20294664/1630171) is correct, it doesn't properly explain the reason for the error you're getting, so I'm adding a supplementary answer.

The error is caused by the identifier `ForReading` in the line

```
set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\Entries1.txt", ForReading)
```

The [`OpenTextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method accepts an optional second parameter `iomode` that can have a value of either `1`, `2` or `8`. However, contrary to what the documentation suggests, there are no pre-defined constants for these numeric values. Unless you define them yourself (which you didn't), e.g. like this:

```
Const ForReading   = 1
Const ForWriting   = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
```

you **must** use the numeric values or omit the parameter entirely (in which case it defaults to `1`).

If you use an undefined identifier like `ForReading` the interpreter will automatically initialize it with the value `Empty`, which could produce unexpected behavior as it did in your case.

Demonstration:

```vbs
>>> WScript.Echo TypeName(ForReading)
Empty
>>> Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\some.txt", ForReading)
Invalid procedure call or argument (0x5)
>>> WScript.Echo TypeName(f)
Empty
>>> Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\some.txt", Empty)
Invalid procedure call or argument (0x5)
>>> WScript.Echo TypeName(f)
Empty
>>> 'parameter omitted
>>> Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\some.txt")
>>> WScript.Echo TypeName(f)
TextStream
>>> Set f = Nothing
>>> 'numeric parameter
>>> Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\some.txt", 1)
>>> WScript.Echo TypeName(f)
TextStream
>>> Set f = Nothing
>>> 'define identifier before using it as parameter
>>> ForReading = 1
>>> WScript.Echo TypeName(ForReading)
Integer
>>> Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\some.txt", ForReading)
>>> WScript.Echo TypeName(f)
TextStream
```

You can avoid this kind of issue by using [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29) (which is highly recommended for production code). It will raise a run-time error when there are undefined variables in your code, allowing you to detect problems like this early on.

Comment: +1. Nice catch. As there were other variables used that weren't declared, I assumed (yeah, I know) that `ForReading` had been declared elsewhere. My VBS is rusty. :-) Nicely explained.

Comment: This will be a common occurrence when changing code from early binding to late binding.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer that addresses the broader issue.