# Send special character like "é" using VBscript SendKey

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I'm trying to use `SendKeys` to send some special characters, for example `é`.

If I use

```
set mySendKeys = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
mySendKeys.SendKeys "é"
```

For sure it won't work...

I'm thinking that interpret the character by using `asc("é")`, get its result is `chr(233)`, then `mySendKeys.SendKeys chr(233)`

Sounds good?... But it will generate an error `Invalid procedure call or argument`

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090602/error-while-sending-character-with-sendkeys-in-vbscript)

Or is there any other way to simulate keyboard to input special character like this?

Comment: This is not a key on the keyboard and doesn't have a virtual key code. SendKeys is not international-aware and a poor solution to most problems. Any test automation tool should have a more robust facility for doing this, like Microsoft's own UI Automation.

Comment: I noticed you tagged this as an UFT question. Is there a special reason to use `SendKeys` instead of using the `.Set` method of the object? As mentioned by @Cody, `SendKeys` is a poor solution and I would avoid it

Answer (score 1):

You should try it like this :

```
set ws = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
ws.SendKeys chr(233)
```

**EDIT :**

```
Dim i,x,a,ws
i = InputBox("Entrer un caractère ou une phrase pour obtenir son Code Unicode Correspondant !","test","éè@!%")
If i <> "" Then
    For x = 1 To Len(i)
        If x <> Len(i) Then
            a = a & "ChrW(" & AscW(Mid(i,x,1)) & ")" & "&"
        Else
            a = a & "ChrW(" & AscW(Mid(i,x,1)) & ")"
        End if
    Next
    Inputbox "Le Code Unicode Correspondant pour " & qq(i) & " est:",,a
End If

wscript.sleep 5000
set ws = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
ws.SendKeys qq(i)
'******************************************************************
Function qq(strIn)
    qq = Chr(34) & strIn & Chr(34)
End Function
'******************************************************************
```

Comment: @nwpulele i don't understand your aim, but anyway, try my edit !

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I executed your code and it only output `"@!` seems still can't send `éè` and `%` is missing... I'll continue try...

Comment: @nwpulele Can you edit your question and paste your hole code, because for me it works and i get `éè@!%`